# A cellular automata code to simulate the spread of an epidemic

Tags: python, simulation, cellular-automata

I'm only beggining at python so sorry if my question seems simple. I want to simulate the spread of an epidemic using cellular autamata. Here's my code :

```
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import random as rd
import copy
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap


def init_graph():
    plt.hlines(y=np.arange(n)+0.5, xmin=-0.5, xmax=n-0.5, linewidth=0.25, color="grey")
    plt.vlines(x=np.arange(n)+0.5, ymin=-0.5, ymax=n-0.5, linewidth=0.25, color="grey")


def init_matrix_array(n):
    m = np.ones((n, n))
    m[n//2][n//2]=2
    return m.tolist()


def next_to_ill_cell(current_state_matrix, i, j):
    for x in [i-1,i,i+1]:
        for y in [j-1,j,j+1]:
            if not((x==i and y==j) or x==-1 or y==-1 or x==n or y==n):
                if current_state_matrix[x][y]==ill:
                    return True
    return False

#Rules
def process_next_state (current_state_matrix):
    previous_state_matrix = copy.deepcopy(current_state_matrix)
    for i in range (n) :
        for j in range (n) :
            if previous_state_matrix[i][j] == untouched:
                if next_to_ill_cell(previous_state_matrix, i, j)== True:
                    k = rd.random()#random
                    if k >= 0.5:
                        current_state_matrix[i][j] = ill
                    else:
                        current_state_matrix[i][j] = untouched

            if previous_state_matrix[i][j]==ill:
                s = rd.random()
                if s >= 0.02875:
                    current_state_matrix[i][j] = recovered
                else:
                    current_state_matrix[i][j] = dead

    return current_state_matrix

def number_of_death(current_state_matrix):
    n_death = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if current_state_matrix[i][j] == dead:
                n_death += 1
    return n_death

def number_of_recovery(previous_state_matrix, current_state_matrix):
    """Calculate the number of recovery"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmap = ListedColormap(['k','w','r','b'])
    dead = 0
    untouched = 1
    ill = 2
    recovered = 3
    n = 50 #number of array (table of 50*50 : 2500 cells)

    init_graph()
    current_state_matrix = init_matrix_array(n)
    day = 1
    while day < 10:
        previous_state_matrix = current_state_matrix

        # Number of death
        n_death = number_of_death(current_state_matrix)
        plt.imshow(current_state_matrix, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=3)
        plt.text(25, 5, f'day = {day}', horizontalalignment='center')
        plt.text(25, 45, f'number of death = {n_death}', horizontalalignment='center')
        current_state_matrix = process_next_state(current_state_matrix)
        day += 1
        plt.pause(1)
   
    plt.show()
```

I guess it could be greatly improved but as I said I am a beginner.

I want an infected cell to stay infected for between 4 and 8 days. How should I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use probabilistic rules where, for example:

- Each cell has either a counter of how many days it has been infected or some kind of timestamp to compare to the current CA step.
- An infected cell starts with 100% chance of remaining infected on the next day and that probability remains as 100% until 4 days have elapsed.
- Starting on the fifth day, reduce that probability by some amount. Repeat this every following day that the cell is still infected.
- If it is still infected on the eighth day, make the probability of it remaining infected zero.